# Pushing lists and files using Pushbullet API

Tags: curl, push

I'm trying to push files and lists using the Pushbullet API. Although I'm successful pushing notes, location and links, lists and files cause me trouble.
Pushbullet API doc says that I need to make sure to provide a JSON body when pushing list items. When I fetch the push history the output is this:

`{
      "type": "list",
      "title": "asadasd",
      "items": [
        {
          "checked": false,
          "text": "q23q2e"
        },
        {
          "checked": false,
          "text": "wqeqwe"
        }
      ]
    }`

When I try to push a list using the same style for items, only the title gets pushed.

`curl -u v1NETDRZc44VyH7xOZHqxbhbrro0P4MhZZujxJoYvihTU:     https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -d type=list -d title=ShoppingList -d items=    [{"checked":false,"text":"Item 1"},{"checked":false,"text":"Item 2"}]`

Also, how do we provide the file path to the file_name parameter of the upload-file http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says on the Pushbullet API doc that all POSTs and GETs are in JSON format. So when POSTing, use content type "application/json" and JSON body.